# Why is #include <string> needed for string objects but not string literals?

Tags: c++, string, header-files

How come when using the string object for variables and parameters you need to have `#include <string>`, but you don't need it for string literals? For example, you can say `cout << "This is a string literal";` without `#include <string>`.

I am learning C++ using a Deitel Brothers book and came up with this question when learning character arrays.

Comment: The library provides an overloaded binary [`operator <<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for `std::ostream&` and  `const char *` (which, btw, can sometimes rear unexpectedly).

Comment: Sidenote: Deitel father and son if I remember correctly.

Comment: String literals are not `string`s. They are constant arrays of characters.

Comment: ...and `std::cout` is designed to print arrays of characters as strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A string literal is not a `std::string` object, it's an array of `const char`.
`"This is a string literal"` has the type `const char[25]`.

In most situations – including this one – an array implicitly decays into a pointer to its first element, and there is an `operator<<` overload for `const char*`.

It's pretty confusing that "string" means several different things in C++, but after a while (and pulling of hair and gnashing of teeth) the intended meaning will be clear from context.

Comment: Fwiw, you can use `"foo"s` to get string, string literal

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, but to use that syntax, you need C++14 or later, and still require `#include <string>`

Answer (score 2):

A string literal like `"This is a string literal"` is of type `const char[25]`, not of type `std::string`. Statement `cout << "This is a string literal"` actually calls `operator <<(ostream&, const char*)`, and the string literal parameter decays to type `const char*`. There isn't any `std::string` involved in this case.